# Using Eclipse with C++Builder 2007?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, c++builder

I have several (huge) projects written with CodeGear C++Builder 2007, making use of components, forms/"designs", etc.

Problem: The IDE sucks, especially the lack of proper navigation in the code gets on my nerves. I'm looking for an alternative IDE to use at least for the actual coding (and maybe for forms-design as well) that can read C++Builder projects (.cproj files).

I thought, if any open IDE can do it, its Eclipse... Other alternatives are welcome if you know them. But before I spend too much time trying to figure out how to make that work--- Does anyone have experience with this and can confirm/decline whether I can use Eclipse to work on C++Builder projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Eclipse works as an IDE with C++Builder.  I regularly do my coding in Eclipse and use C++Builder for the compiling, form designer, and debugging.  (Eclipse should be able to invoke a command-line build of C++Builder and look for errors, but I've never tried this.)

Eclipse doesn't need to be able to read .cbproj files; instead, create an Eclipse project in the same directory as your C++Builder project, manually set up your Eclipse paths and includes to match your C++Builder project, and let Eclipse go from there.

I'm currently using Eclipse Helios, which is rather old.  Newer versions of Eclipse CDT improve its ability to parse C++, but unfortunately, this seems to cause it to reject more of C++Builder's C++ extensions.  I haven't yet investigated to see how to best handle this.

Comment: Josh, thanks. So I'm loosing the 'I' of my IDE, but at least I have an editor that one can actually work with. :/